# Paypal PDT is not returning all variables

Tags: php, paypal

I am new to Paypal Payment Data Transfer (PDT), and I am trying to get PDT to return the following variables and print them on the confirmation page: first_name, last_name, payer_email, payment_gross, item_number, item_name, payment_date.  I used the PHP code from Github to get PDT to work (https://github.com/paypal/pdt-code-samples/blob/master/paypal_pdt.php), and it is only returning the variables  first_name, last_name, payer_email and payment_gross.  PDT doesn't return the variables payment_date, item_number and item_name.  Can anyone see what is my problem?

Here is the PHP code for the confirmation page, where users are returned after paying for an item on Paypal:

```
<?php

$pp_hostname = "www.sandbox.paypal.com";


// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-synch';

$tx_token = $_GET['tx'];
$auth_token = "O1UZLXPTewPRo9cWvtdU5fSEB0KH4PerJcyTKCJzj-yiZi2JOQzZcjwTf1G";
$req .= "&tx=$tx_token&at=$auth_token";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://$pp_hostname/cgi-bin/webscr");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
//set cacert.pem verisign certificate path in curl using 'CURLOPT_CAINFO' field here,
//if your server does not bundled with default verisign certificates.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Host: $pp_hostname"));
$res = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

if(!$res){
//HTTP ERROR

echo ("<p><h3>ERROR!</h3></p>");

}
else{  echo ("<p><h3>THIS WOKRED!</h3></p>");
// parse the data
$lines = explode("\n", $res);
$keyarray = array();
if (strcmp ($lines[0], "SUCCESS") == 0) {
for ($i=1; $i<count($lines);$i++){
list($key,$val) = explode("=", $lines[$i]);
$keyarray[urldecode($key)] = urldecode($val);
}
// check the payment_status is Completed
// check that txn_id has not been previously processed
// check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
// check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
// process payment
$firstname = $keyarray['first_name'];
$lastname = $keyarray['last_name'];
$itemname = $keyarray['item_name'];
$amount = $keyarray['payment_gross'];
$itemnumber = $keyarray['item_number'];
$payeremail = $keyarray['payer_email'];
$paymentdate = $keyarray['payment_datel'];


echo ("<p><h3>Thank you for your purchase!</h3></p>");

echo ("<b>Payment Details</b><br>\n");
echo ("<li>Name: $firstname $lastname</li>\n");
echo ("<li>Item: $itemname</li>\n");
echo ("<li>Amount: $amount</li>\n");
echo ("<li>Item Number: $itemnumber</li>\n");
echo ("<li>Payer Email: $payeremail</li>\n");
echo ("<li>Payment Date: $paymentdate</li>\n");

echo ("");
}
else if (strcmp ($lines[0], "FAIL") == 0) {
// log for manual investigation  
echo ("<p><h3>ERROR NUMBER TWO!</h3></p>");}
}

?>
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line `if (strcmp ($lines[0], "SUCCESS") == 0)`  to this `if (strcmp ($lines[1], "SUCCESS") == 0)`

And

Change this line `else if (strcmp ($lines[0], "FAIL") == 0)`  to this `else if (strcmp ($lines[1], "FAIL") == 0)`

OR

Simply replace by using much better code;
Change this line `if (strcmp ($lines[0], "SUCCESS") == 0)` to this `if (stripos($lines, "SUCCESS") !== false)`

And

Again, with better code;
Change this line  `else if (strcmp ($lines[0], "FAIL") == 0)` to this `if (stripos($lines, "FAIL") !== false)`

That should do it! :-)
It sucks that paypal likes to throw out wack code for us coders/developers to fix. Have a great day!

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem with same script, and unfortunately this solution did not work for me.